# Не открывает некоторые страницы сайта при использовании обратного прокси-сервера

Tags: apache, tomcat, axis2

Установил томкат и axis2, когда делаю обращение по локальному адресу открывает все страницы нормально, а если обращаться по внешнему адресу не открывает некоторые страницы axis. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот по локальному адресу 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в /conf/server.xml прописаны такие настройки, больше и не менял кроме этого файла

```
<Server port="8007" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"  SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">            
<Connector acceptCount="70" connectionTimeout="20000"
        disableUploadTimeout="false" port="82"  redirectPort="443"
    address="127.0.0.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" debug="99">
  </Connector>         
  <Connector acceptCount="70" connectionTimeout="20000"
      disableUploadTimeout="false" port="82"  redirectPort="443"
     address="10.0.27.32" URIEncoding="UTF-8" debug="99">
  </Connector>     
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="testpay.kkb.kz">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">                 
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

        <Host name="testpay.kkb.kz"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false" 
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">                          
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />               

  </Host>
  </Engine>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, под "внешним адресом" вы понимаете обратный прокси-сервер. Тогда вам надо настроить атрибуты `proxyName` и `proxyPort` у элемента `Connector`, отвечающего за прослушивание HTTP-запросов.

Comment: проблема оказывается в том что в axis ссылка на список его сервисов сслыалется без https, если я добавляю https в адресной строке все работает, как это можно исправить, чтобы если на сервер обращаются без https она переадресовывала